# Linux permissions and dnscrypt-proxy (Network permission?)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, proxy

I asked this on "ask Ubuntu" and had much luck yet, so I thought I might try here as well
https://askubuntu.com/questions/409660/dnscrypt-proxy-works-but-with-incorrect-permissions

I have successfully installed and find myself in the middle of configuring dnscrypt-proxy on ubuntu 13.10 x64.  However, I am running into some issues with permissions in general.

I have added a user with the following commmand:

`sudo adduser --system --quiet --home /run/dnscrypt --shell /bin/false --group --disabled-password --disabled-login dnscrypt`

and issued `dnscrypt-proxy --daemonize --user=dnscrypt` but without success.  So i tried just `--daemonize` and finally just `dnscrypt-proxy` which resulted in a UDP bind permission error.  Ran it as **root** and the error goes away.  `dnscrypt-proxy --user=dnscrypt` results in the error returning.  I'm guessing its failing because of some permission, but don't have a clue where to start or what to change at this point.

also i would like to run this at network startup or after login.  which i think i can manage, but if you have a suggestion it would just save me time.  I don't understand why I can't run this as `--user=dnscrypt` but root works fine.  (I mean, I understand why root works ;D)

edit:  Just to clarify a little more, I'm actually running elementary OS luna 0.2, which is based on ubuntu 13.10 (I believe)

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to correctly set [**cap_net_bind_service**](https://github.com/jedisct1/dnscrypt-proxy/wiki/Installation-linux) on the `dnscrypt-proxy` binary so that it can `bind` to port `53` while running as the **non root** (`dnscrypt`) user:

```
setcap cap_net_bind_service=+pe /path/to/dnscrypt-proxy
```

If you run `dnscrypt-proxy` inside an `lxc` container the above command will need to be executed from the `host`.

Another option in 2023 for running `rootless` services is to set a `sysctl` value:

`net.ipv4.ip_unprivileged_port_start=53`

Comment: Your solution is not ubuntu specific. In artix linux (arch variant) is correct too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an init script that should use start-stop-daemon to drop the privileges.

The app probably requires raw socket access and for such an operation root (or CAP_SOCK) is required. It is not possible as a normal user.

This link should be quite usefull: http://linuxmint.tumblr.com/post/29714225010/installing-dnscrypt

Comment: Couldn't it also be that ports under 1024 can't be used by non-root users?